# Unwanted InResponseTo attribute in SAML Response

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am using AAD B2C as an IDP and it is sending SAML Response to PingOne but in that response, there is an attribute **InResponseTo** attribute which has an ID of AuthnRequest and PingOne fails the request because of it.

https://community.pingidentity.com/PingOne/PingOne-General/SAML-223-The-request-you-sent-is-outdated-This-can-be-due-to-an-old-entry-in-the-browser-cache-or-a-bookmark-to-a-transient-login-page-Try-restarting-your-browser-and-using-the-application-URL-again.

I followed following documents to create custom policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md

**AuthNRequest**

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
ID="F84D888AA3B44C1B844375A4E8210D9E" 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" 
Version="2.0" 
IsPassive="false"   
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/
sso/sp/ACS.saml2" 
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer 
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">  
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/
      TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/POLICY_NAME
    </Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
        format:unspecified">
    </samlp:NameIDPolicy>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

By using above AuthnRequest I created encoded SAMLRequest and hit below URL
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/POLICY_NAME/samlp/sso/login?SAMLRequest=ENCODED_AUTHNREQUEST_SAML&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fpingone.com%2F1.0%2FENTITY_ID

**SAML Response**

```
<samlp:Response 
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    ID="_18b91c0a-e117-4c0d-877b-12e1627fbfd0" 
    InResponseTo="F84D888AA3B44C1B844375A4E8210D9E" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2017-10-02T16:25:45.6637019Z" 
    Destination="https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/sso/sp/ACS.saml2" 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/saml
    </saml:Issuer>
    <Signature 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      .....
    </Signature> 
    <samlp:Status>
      .....
    </samlp:Status> 
    <saml:Assertion >
      .....
    </saml:Assertion>
```

Comment: The error you mentioned in your question is "SAML_223: The request you sent is outdated" isn't related to the "InResponseTo" attribute and can happen when the IDP and SP clocks are not tuned to the same hour (Usually different timezones or one of the clocks is not adjusted).
Regarding the issue of PingOne failing the request because of the "InResponseTo" attribute - did you try to remove it from the response? not all implementations requires it.

Comment: When I removed the attribute "InResponseTo" on my own and then SAML was sent to PingOne through PingOne then it was not getting this error.

Comment: So can you not send the "InResponseTo" attribute? or it's not something you can configure?

Comment: I do not want to send "InResponseTo" attribute. How can I make this IDP initiated SSO?